# What is MLE of $U[-k,7k]$?

Tags: uniform-distribution, estimation, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

I need to find maximum likelihood estimator of uniform distribution $X : U[-k,7k]$.
I think that the answer is $max\{x_1, ..., x_n \}$ . However, I think I have a mistake because if $X : U[0,k]$ the answer would be the same. So, it seems strange to me why MLE does not depend on the length of the interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $k = 1$ and your sample is $(-0.9, 0.2, 2.5, 3.7, 4.2)$.  Based on the sample maximum $4.2$, your estimate of $k$ would be $(4.2)/7 = 0.6$.  But based on the sample *minimum*, $-0.9$, your estimate would be $0.9$.  Which one is better?  Can you think of a way to write a mathematical expression to reflect this?

---

Here is the sufficient statistic calculation.

Let the sample be $\boldsymbol x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$, and as usual, define the minimum and maximum order statistics $x_{(1)} = \min \boldsymbol x$, $x_{(n)} = \max \boldsymbol x$, respectively.  Then we have $$f(\boldsymbol x \mid k) = \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{8k} \mathbb 1 (-k \le x_i \le 7k) = (8k)^{-n} \mathbb 1 (-k \le x_{(1)} \le x_{(n)} \le 7k).$$  So by the Factorization theorem, a sufficient statistic is $T(\boldsymbol x) = (x_{(1)}, x_{(n)})$.  This happens to be minimal, but it is not necessary to prove this.  The point of finding $T$ is to show that any MLE of $k$ will be expressible as a function of $T$.

As for the MLE, we have the likelihood
$$\mathcal L(k \mid x_{(1)}, x_{(n)}) \propto k^{-n} \mathbb 1(-k \le x_{(1)} \le x_{(n)} \le 7k).$$  Because $k^{-n}$ is a monotone decreasing function of $k$, $\mathcal L$ is maximized for the **smallest** possible positive choice of $k$ that keeps the indicator function equal to $1$; that is to say, we require that $k \ge x_{(n)}/7$ *and* $k \ge -x_{(1)}$.  Equivalently, $$k \ge \max\left(\frac{x_{(n)}}{7}, -x_{(1)}\right).$$  Therefore, the desired MLE is $$\hat k = \max\left(\frac{x_{(n)}}{7}, -x_{(1)}\right).$$

Comment: 0.9 is closer to 1, so it's better. If I write formula $(\frac{1}{8k})^n \to min$, does this mean that I need to take $\hat k = min(x_1,..x_n)$?

Comment: @Bruh The point I am trying to make is that the "best" estimate depends on which of the sample maximum versus sample minimum is closer to $7k$ or $-k$, respectively.  Your estimator, which only looks at the maximum, doesn't do that.  Neither does looking only at the minimum.  You have to look at *both*.  How would you decide which one is better, and how would you write that into a formula?

Comment: Let $d_1 = 7k - max(x_1,..x_n)$ and $d_2 = k + min(x_1,..x_n)$
$\hat k_{ML} = max(x_1,..x_n)/7 \cdot I(d1 \leq d2) + min(x_1,..x_n) \cdot I(d1 > d2)$, but we don't know real $k$.

Comment: @Bruh That's a good try, but it's not an estimator because $\hat k$ as you defined it, is a function of the unknown parameter $k$.  Your estimator can only depend on the sample.  Have you tried finding a sufficient statistic for $k$?  Here's another hint.  Let $x_{(n)}$ be the sample maximum, and $x_{(1)}$ the sample minimum.  Compare $x_{(n)}/7$ versus $-x_{(1)}$.

Comment: Ok, I use Fisher–Neyman theorem and Indicator function. Here I have an indicator $I(-k \leq x_i \leq 7k)$, hence the sufficient statistics seems to consist of both $x_{(1)}$ and $x_{(n)}$...

Comment: @Bruh See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that for any $X_i$ you have that

$$-k\leq X_i\leq 7k$$

thus

$$\begin{cases}
-k\leq X_{(1)} \\
7k\geq X_{(n)}
\end{cases}$$

Thus

$$k\geq \max\left(-X_{(1)};\frac{X_{(n)}}{7}\right)$$

Given that the likelihood ($1/(8k)^n$) is strictly decreasing in $k$

$$T=\max\left(-X_{(1)};\frac{X_{(n)}}{7}\right)$$

is MLE